# "Run Anything" action doesn't work for maven commands

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

While the "Run anything" works fine for other commands It does nothing for the maven ones, literally, It does nothing! For instance, I want to run a `mvn clean install` using "Run anything" action:

[image]

Hitting enter does not show the Run tool window, nor does it show an error message. Again, It does nothing. Note that other commands are working fine.

I am used to running maven commands using this strategy. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the described problem in IntelliJ [IDEA 2019.3.4 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and in [2020.1 RC](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) versions.

If the issue persists for you in these versions, please share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) file, there must be some exception logged which may help to understand why it doesn't work for you. Most likely, updating the IDE and running with the default settings/plugins per [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559) will solve the issue.

Also make sure you have a valid Maven project with the JDK and Maven properly configured in the IDE settings.

Comment: Great! I've managed to solve the issue just by upgrading from IDEA 2019.2.3 to 2019.3.4